# Linux ACPI errors + boot problems on my laptop

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, 19.04, acpi

I recently bought an HP 17-cb0011nv laptop and I was trying to install Linux on it. I tried to install several distros on it, like Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 and even 19.10. The installation process was very buggy and after multiple tries I was able to install all of the above versions of Ubuntu. But none of them were stable. During the startup sequence the most frequent outcome were either a blank screen or the splash screen running indefinitely.

When on the splash screen, by pressing F3 I would get a fast never ending scrolling wall of text with ACPI errors. I then tried to boot with `ACPI=off` from the grub menu and as a result it would crash around 30 seconds of usage or get a kernel panic (more often). After that I tried several other flags like `nolapic` which seem to work more often (even though the performance suffers greatly). I am seriously very frustrated by this, and I have spent a lot of time already trying to fix it. Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

kernel panic:

[image: kernel panic]

ACPI errors:

[image: ACPI error]

[image: ACPI error 2]

Comment: You should have used pictures from an on-topic release;  19.10 is off-topic on this site until it's release as it's a development release and bug reports belong on launchpad (and support for 19.10 is not available here).

Comment: The ACPI errors were the same on all the versions I mentioned. I don't think that the kernel version matters in this case, since I was getting similar behavior even when I was using "on-topic" releases.

Answer (score 1):

A user from another forum suggested me, to use the boot flag `pci=nommconf`. This has worked great so far.